# How to get the date of a day in a month in certain year?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I want to get the dates of , for example the dates of Sunday during September 2011 in sql sever 2005, or in c#
so the result should be
4/9/2011
11/9/2011
18/9/2011
25/9/2011

Comment: 7 questions, no accepts, no votes, and no attempt to solve on your own.  I see a pattern here...

Comment: Maybe no accepts, but the question is basically fine.

Answer (score 2):

First I'd create a `DateTime` using the first day of that month.

From there, I'd pick the `DayOfWeek` property, do some math (subtract/add) to find the right date that week that matched the date you want.

From there, I'd keep calling `DateTime.AddDays(7)`, and return those values until the month property rolled over.

I'd write a function that did this, that takes a year, a month, and a `DayOfWeek`.  It would return an `IEnumerable<DateTime>`, and `yield return` each value.

Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var date in DayOfWeek.Monday.OccurrencesInMonth(year: 2011, month: 8))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
    }
}

public static class DayOfWeekExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> OccurrencesInMonth(this DayOfWeek targetDayOfWeek, int year, int month)
    {
        var firstDayInYear = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
        var currentDay = firstDayInYear.Next(targetDayOfWeek);

        while (currentDay.Month == month)
        {
            yield return currentDay;
            currentDay = currentDay.AddDays(7);
        }
    }
}

public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime Next(this DateTime current, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        int offsetToNextOccurrence = dayOfWeek - current.DayOfWeek;
        if (offsetToNextOccurrence < 0)
            offsetToNextOccurrence += 7;
        return current.AddDays(offsetToNextOccurrence);
    }
}
```

> 8/1/2011 12:00:00 AM
>   8/8/2011 12:00:00 AM
>   8/15/2011 12:00:00 AM
>   8/22/2011 12:00:00 AM
>   8/29/2011 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

.NET C#

DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 6, 11);
Console.WriteLine((int) dateValue.DayOfWeek);      // Displays 3

From a search on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I didnt really understand what you want. but i will answer as i think i understand.

Frist of all we do this on your code:
This code if for C#

DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

string timenow;

you can do this - timenow = time.timeofday.tostring();
witch wil give us: 21:44:15.3487
or we can do - timenow = time.ToLongDateString();
it will give us the date.

There is also Time.ToShortDateString();.

Just take the function that you think you need.

In SQL you can alaways do "GetDate()".

I think i help, happy if i did :)

Comment: what i want is to get the dates of all Sundays in certain month in a certain year as if u see September has 4 Sundays on 4/9/2011, 11/9/2011, 18/9/2011, 25/9/2011, so i want to get this 4 dates in sql server

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = '20110801' 

SELECT  DATEADD(dd, number, @Date) Date
FROM    master..spt_values
WHERE   YEAR(DATEADD(dd, number, @Date)) = YEAR(@Date) AND MONTH(DATEADD(dd, number, @Date)) = MONTH(@Date) AND DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(dd, number, @Date)) = 1
        AND [Type] = 'p'
```